# Want to fill WinJS.UI.ListView with my own data

Tags: winjs

I had got the data using

```
WinJS.xhr({ url: url, responseType: "json" }).then(
     function(result){},
     function(error){}
);
```

I make this stuff on the button click event. 
I got the data properly but can not fill them in my ListView.
So now, how can I bind the JSON data in my WinJS.UI.ListView on every click of button with my new data...? please help me for this with some simple example. because I had already checked so many links. But still I could not understand where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should go something like this:

```
WinJS.xhr({ .. }).then(function xhrcomplete(req)
{
    var data; // assuming you already have code that parsed json text to an object.
    var items = [];
    // fill code here to get items out of the data
    var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(items);
    // binding code will depend on whether listview has groupHeaderTemplate or not
    // if not - it should be like this
    listView.winControl.itemDataSource = list.dataSource; // listView is the id of the your list view control in html

}).then(null, function onerror(error)
{
    // handle error case
});
```

Comment: I got this error:Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 10299, column 5 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.1.0/js/ui.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createListBinding'

Comment: This is my ListView control: 
<div id="listView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"></div>

Comment: without this line its not giving me any kind of error or exception: listView.winControl.itemDataSource = list;

Comment: oops missed the `list.dataSource`